# masterview is not a member of telerik.wincontrols.Ui.radgridview

Tags: vb.net, telerik, radgridview

I am trying to add a row but to a radgridview but it show this error. which header file should I import.

```
Dim rowInfo As New GridViewDataRowInfo(Me.radgridview1.MasterView)

radgridview1.Rows.Add(rowInfo)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put that in design mode:

```
<asp:ToolkitScriptManager ID="ToolkitScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

And download toolkit script

Comment: It's a windows forms application not a web application. So I can't use asp code